# Imported settings into WinSCP but sessions still not showing

Tags: windows, registry, winscp

I followed this guide trying to copy session information from my old Windows install to the new one:

https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_transfer_config

The old session information does appear in the registry in the new computer, but when I close and reopen WinSCP, the sessions aren't there. Is there a step I'm missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the answer - newer versions of WinSCP create a winscp.ini file in the `C:\Program Files(x86)\WinSCP` directory. Removing this makes WinSCP use the registry keys.

Comment: This is not really true. First, WinSCP can hardly have write access to `C:\Program Files(x86)`, you need an Administrator privileges to do so. Are you running WinSCP with Administrator privileges? Second, installed WinSCP defaults to using registry, not INI file. So the only explanation is that you actually didn't install WinSCP, but copied the binaries manually to the "Program Files". Did you? For details, see https://winscp.net/eng/docs/config

Comment: You don't have to have administrator access to install to C:¥Program Files(x86), but yes, I do have local admin access. I DID install WinSCP on a new install and then imported the registry settings as described in the link I provided. However, when I ran WinSCP, my previous sessions wouldn't show up. I manually removed the reg keys, uninstalled, reinstalled, re-added the keys, no dice. There was a  winscp.ini file on the new install and Google searches mentioned this. I removed it and restarted WinSCP. BAM! Old sessions were back. Sorry if this isn't normal but it worked.

Comment: 1) Sure you have to have administrator access to install to "Program Files". Since Windows Vista, no application, unless running with elevated privileges, can write to Program Files. 2) WinSCP installer does not create winscp.ini. On the other hand WinSCP uninstaller deletes the winscp.ini, if any. So what you write does not make any sense. Unless the winscp.ini was actually in the virtual store (created by some very old version of WinSCP). - How did you locate/delete the winscp.ini? Using what tool? 3) *"Google searches mentioned this"* - What "searches"?

Comment: 1) In WinXP you could be a "Power User", but that's old I guess. 2) Somehow a "winscp.ini" was magically created when I reinstalled. You're the programmer you would know better than I. Locating a non-hidden system file like winscp.ini is pretty easy; do you really need an answer? 3) Let me rephrase "I searched on Google and people mentioned problems with winscp.ini, which led me to look for it." Hope this is clear now. All I can tell you is importing the reg keys did NOT work but finding and removing "winscp.ini" DID work. No need to get testy, just saying this worked for me.

Comment: So are you using Windows XP?